# Exception Handling using a Constructor (JAVA)

Tags: java, class, oop, exception

I'm currently working on a project in which I am to ask the user to input 2 numbers, divide them, and then throw an exception if the denominator is 0.

I feel like I'm close but I can figure out how to get the sysout from the constructor to print when the exception is thrown. Also, the instructions I'm following state I "must" add a try/catch in order to call the divide method.

Within the code I've added comments with numbered instructions I'm following. I've been trying to follow them to the best of my abilities, but I can't figure out:

1. How to get constructor to throw the exception
2. How to use a try/catch to call the method.

I have a feeling I'm supposed to be using a subclass to access the constructor.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the Exception class:

```
public class DivisionException {
    
    
    public DivisionException () {

        System.out.println("Error: you cannot divide by zero");
        
    }
    
}
```

And here is the Main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExceptionHandling {

    public void Divide (double num, double den) {
        
      
        if(den == 0) {

            throw new ArithmeticException("How do I get 'Error: you cannot divide by zero' from the constructor to print when the exception is thrown?");

                
        } else {
            
           
            System.out.println(num/den);
                
        }
        

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           
        

        System.out.println("Welcome to the division calculator.\nPlease enter the dividend: ");
        double num = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Now please enter the divisor: ");        
        double den = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(num + " divided by " + den + " equals: ");

       
        ExceptionHandling a = new ExceptionHandling();        
        a.Divide(num, den);


    }

}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception doesn't mean printing an error message. I suggest you to start reading [about Java exceptions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-exceptions), and then reading [how to define and throw your own exceptions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-new-custom-exception). Hint: in the constructor you take the two numbers. If the denominator is zero, you throw your exception that you catch and use to print in the main method. Also, from a clean-code perspective, it's not really nice to throw in a constructor. I'd rather declare a method divide on the same class which throws if denominator=0

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment! Thank you for providing those links and for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

package modelo;

public class Divicion {

```
private double numerator;
private double denominator;

public Divicion() {
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
}

public double getNumerator() {
    return numerator;
}

public void setNumerator(double numerator) {
    this.numerator = numerator;
}

public double getDenominator() {
    return denominator;
}

public void setDenominator(double denominator) {
    this.denominator = denominator;
}

public double operation() throws Exception {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new Exception("You cannot divide by zero");
    }
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

}

package calculadora;

import modelo.Divicion;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculadora {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double cDivide;

    Divicion divide = new Divicion();
    System.out.print("Enter the numerator: ");
    divide.setNumerator(sc.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Enter the denominator: ");
    divide.setDenominator(sc.nextDouble());

    try {
        cDivide =  divide.operation();
        System.out.println("Result: "+ cDivide);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error.\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Remember that in the classes it is not recommended message outputs by console,
also that a constructor is not designed to throw exceptions its functionality 
is based on the isolation of its attributes to the default value or a value
according to what is required that is to say overloaded constructor, not having 
java constructor implements the default constructor that is to say all its attributes
have their default value.
In this example use the Exception since it is the most generalized of the eceptions 
but you can change it for an ArithmeticException I hope it will serve you. Luck!!

Comment: I am currently away from my PC, but I’ll do my best to take the code and information you’ve provided and implement them into my program.